# Sql programming Language

Tags: sql

Scenario:

Lets assume I have an order Id 1001 ,where we have five products being ordered in That order (1001)..When we had issue in any one of the Product,we will assign a customer executive to solve that issue and there will be a customer executive resolved date for that one Product..I want that date to be applied for all the four Products which is present within that same Order Id (1001)...

I have explained it for just one order..Consider a Situation where you have thousands of Order Id s. How to map them

Eg:

1001: P1,P2,P3,P4,P5

Since there is some issue with Product P2,the issue was forwarded to Cet and Once they resolve We have Cet Resolved Date

I want the same date to be replicated in P1,P3,P4,P5

In case 
We had Issue with P2,P3 they pick the max of two dates and replicated in P1,P4,P5

Same case should be applied for other Order Ids too

Comment: Please choose a more meaningful title, add schema info, add sample data, add expected output, add what you've tried and why it didn't work. I don't understand your problem

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution would be to Create a `before update` trigger

- Capture the incoming `order id` and `cet_resolved_date`.
- Find the `max(date)` for that `order_id` and compare with incoming `et_resolved_date`. Which ever is maximum, save that in a variable.
- Run an update statement for that `order_id` and set other `dates` with the `date` saved in the variable.
- Suppose `1001`.`P2` got an updated date, then before updating it, this trigger will execute, capture the `cet_resolved_date` and see if this is the maximum date among other products. Else it will save maximum date to a variable and then update other dates of that `order_id` with the variable value.

Warning: It will slow down bulk updates on your table.